# Functions.php file removing automatically

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress i tried to edit functions.php file, after some modification in code i saved the file, then it got deleted automatically, and site got white blank page,

then i tried to restore the original file but it also deleting automatically again and again. please help!

Comment: How are you editing the file? Through Ftp access?

Comment: em editing it via Cpanel